# Making smooth effect in WPF manually in C# with DispatcherTimer

Tags: wpf, silverlight, effects, dispatcher, smoothing

I'm trying to make pretty effect with not using Storyboard or another ready/already done stuff in WPF.

I want to make smooth effect, where on some event (like click) the UI element resizes for 2-3 seconds and bluring with changing color. All these items I want to make in smooth pretty way.

I have prepared such class to render each frame of my effect:

```
public static class ApplicationHelper
{
        [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand,
        Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
        public static void DoEvents(DispatcherPriority priority)
        {
            DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
            DispatcherOperation oper = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.
                            BeginInvoke(priority,
                            new DispatcherOperationCallback(ExitFrameOperation),
                            frame);

            Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
            if (oper.Status != DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed)
            {
                oper.Abort();
            }
        }

        private static object ExitFrameOperation(object obj)
        {
            ((DispatcherFrame)obj).Continue = false;
            return null;
        }

        [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand,
        Flags=SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
        public static void DoEvents()
        {
            DoEvents(DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
}
```

Here I'm trying to make it work with DispatcherTimer:

```
   void vb1_click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
       dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
       dt.Tick += new System.EventHandler(dt_Tick);
       dt.Start();
   }

   void dt_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
       {
           this.vb2_blur_eff.Radius = (double)i;
           ApplicationHelper.DoEvents();     
       }
   }
```

The main problem is, that when I'm launcing it, I'm only waiting and at the final time ( when must last frame be rendered ) , I'm getting in a very quick speed all frames, but perviously there was nothing.

How to solve it and make perfect smooth effect in pure C# way with not using some ready/done stuff?

Thank you!

Comment: @punker76 it's not reinventing it's implementing

Comment: ok, but why not using the visual states with the visual statemanager?

Comment: @punker76 What do visual stattes and statemanager use? Don't they use DispatcherTimer and work with similar style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ApplicationHelper.DoEvents()` in `dt_Tick` probably does nothing, since there are no events to process. At least not the ones you're probably expecting.

If I'm not mistaken, your code will just quickly set the `Radius` to `0`, then `1`, `2`, and so on in quick succession, and finally to `19`. All of that will happen every 500 milliseconds (on every `Tick`, that is).

I think you might believe that each `Tick` will only set `Radius` to one value and then wait for the next `Tick`, but it does not. Every `Tick` will set the `Radius` to all the values, ending at `19`. That is one possible explanation for what you're experiencing.

I would also like to comment on the `DoEvents` approach. It's most likely a bad idea. Whenever I see a `DoEvents` I get chills up my spine. (It reminds me of some seriously bad Visual Basic 5/6 code I stumbled across 10-15 years ago.) As I see it, an event handler should return control of the GUI thread as quickly as possible. If the operation takes a not insignificant amount of time, then you should delegate that work to a worker thread. And nowadays, you have plenty of options for writing asynchronous code.